# Skip objects conditionally when serializing with jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class like

```
interface IHideable {
   boolean isHidden();
}

class Address implements IHideable {
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private boolean hidden;
}

class PersonalInfo implements IHideable {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean hidden;
}
```

I want to serialize a List of IHideable in my web service; but filter out any object which has the hidden field set to true.

Basically given with a list of objects like

```
[
{'city 1','street 1',false},
{'city 2','street 2',true},
{'city 3','street 3',false}
]
```

I want the output as

```
[
  {
    city:'city 1',
    street:'street 1'
  },
  {
    city:'city 3',
    street:'street 3'
  }
]
```

I tried the following implementation

```
class ItemSerializer extends JsonSerializer<IHideable> {  
    @Override
    public void serialize(IHideable value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        if (!value.isHidden()) {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeString("city", value.city);
            jgen.writeString("street", value.street);
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

But the writeString methods written are specific for Address class. When i use writeObject there it throws stackoverflow exception. Can I use some generic writeObject method which Can write any object which implements IHideable()?
Is this possible with jackson default/custom serialization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `BeanSerializerModifier` to register a serializer for `IHideable` types and get the reference to the default bean serializer as it was discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson) question.

In your serializer you check the `isHidden` flag and if it is not set serialize the instance using the default serializer. That trick should work for any types that implements your `IHideable` interface. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonHide {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("hidden")
    public static interface IHideable {
        boolean isHidden();
    }

    public static class Address implements IHideable {
        public final String city;
        public final String street;
        public final boolean hidden;

        public Address(String city, String street, boolean hidden) {
            this.city = city;
            this.street = street;
            this.hidden = hidden;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isHidden() {
            return hidden;
        }
    }

    public static class PersonalInfo implements IHideable {
        public final String name;
        public final int age;
        public final boolean hidden;

        public PersonalInfo(String name, int age, boolean hidden) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.hidden = hidden;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isHidden() {
            return hidden;
        }
    }

    private static class MyBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
        @Override
        public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config,
                                                  BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                  JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
            if (IHideable.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass())) {
                return new MyIHideableJsonSerializer((JsonSerializer<IHideable>) serializer);
            }
            return super.modifySerializer(config, beanDesc, serializer);
        }

        private static class MyIHideableJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<IHideable> {
            private final JsonSerializer<IHideable> serializer;

            public MyIHideableJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer<IHideable> serializer) {
                this.serializer = serializer;
            }

            @Override
            public void serialize(IHideable value,
                                  JsonGenerator jgen,
                                  SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
                if (!value.isHidden()) {
                     serializer.serialize(value, jgen, provider);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setSerializerModifier(new MyBeanSerializerModifier());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        PersonalInfo p1 = new PersonalInfo("John", 30, false);
        PersonalInfo p2 = new PersonalInfo("Ivan", 20, true);
        Address a1 = new Address("A", "B", false);
        Address a2 = new Address("C", "D", true);

        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString
                (Arrays.asList(p1, p2, a1, a2)));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[ {
  "name" : "John",
  "age" : 30
}, {
  "city" : "A",
  "street" : "B"
} ]
```

Comment: I had to use `SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("dummy", new Version(1, 0, 0, null)) { public void setupModule(SetupContext context) { super.setupModule(context);  context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new MySerializerModifier());}};` But otherwise it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I believe this is cyclic inheritance and should be outside , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811904/cyclic-inheritance-when-implementing-inner-interface-in-enum